# how to configure environment variables such as banckend api url in an angular application, since the environment.prod.ts files have been deleted?

Tags: angular, environment-variables, production-environment

I would like to put into production an application developed with Angular (version 15.0.1). in this version of angular, the environment.prod.ts files have been removed. how can I configure an apiUrl variable in this case?

For now it's hard coded in my service as following:

apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080"

how could I modify this values ​​once the application is dokerized so that they correspond to that of the api in production?

Comment: Angular simply doesn't create these files anymore by default.
But you can still create them and configure their replacement based on build target: `ng generate environments` It's explained in the docs: https://angular.io/guide/build#configure-environment-specific-defaults